# mkbundle won't embed assembly with accompanying netmodule

Tags: mono, saxon, mkbundle

I'm trying to mkbundle a Mono app, and it includes a reference to Saxon assemblies. No issues with `saxon9.dll`, but when I try to include `saxon9api.dll` it won't build:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'saxon9api, Version=9.1.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1fdd002d5083fe6' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'saxon9api, Version=9.1.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1fdd002d5083fe6'
  at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.DefaultResolver (System.String refname, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.Load (System.String refname, IKVM.Reflection.Module requestingModule, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.Load (System.String refname) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MakeBundle.QueueAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 files, System.String codebase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Saxon also has a 'netmodule' file, `saxon9api.netmodule`. Not entirely sure what this is, as I've never come across such a thing before. But Saxon won't work without it, and I believe this is what is causing it to fail.

How can I bundle this file?

If I can't bundle it, is there any way to specifically *exclude* it, so I can continue to use the `--deps` option with `mkbundle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon 9.1 is very old now. Back then we required using a netmodule file which contained the the compiled sources of Saxon and was linked to the Assembly.

In the releases from 9.2 onwards we no longer use the netmodule file. Are you not able to move forward?

I don't know enough about mkbundle to say wether the net module can be included. Maybe you should try looking at the option at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/mkbundle2.1.html

Comment: Yes, it seems I can use 9.5 on Mono! I'd seem someone else complaining that 9.4 didn't work on Mono, so had assumed I'd be stuck with 9.1 for the duration